# OWASP ZAP - (Authentication) Extract Token from Response and use it for a next Request

Tags: authentication, access-token, owasp, zap

I am new to ZAP, Could someone please assist with OWASP ZAP with extracting multiple authentications tokens from a Response and use it for next Request Header

Required:
-Login in 
-GET Request A(Response) : {"tokenA":"abcdef","tokenB":"xyz"}
-GET Request B(Header) : Token1:tokenA_Value
-GET Request B(Header) : Token2:tokenB_Value

These Token (A, B) get updated every time user logins, Is there any way where I can store the "tokenA" and "tokenB" values in variables and then use it for a next request header "Token1" and "Token2" ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Script Variables for this: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/script-console/

I gave a 3 hour workshop on ZAP automation and authentication recently for ADDO - that was recorded and the videos are being added to https://www.alldaydevops.com/zap-in-ten